# MS Chart Strip Lines Intraday

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I use a line chart with double in Y axis and DateTime in X axis. My plot has only intraday data: I have one point each minutes between 8 am and 10 pm.

I want to underline certain periods of the plot. The first period begins at 8:50 and continues during 20 minutes. For this I use a stripLine with the following code:

```
var stripLine = new StripLine();
stripLine.BackColor = Color.White;
stripLine.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
stripLine.BackImageTransparentColor = Color.White;
stripLine.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Transparent;
stripLine.Interval = 1;
stripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
stripLine.IntervalOffset = 50;
stripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
stripLine.StripWidth = 20;
stripLine.StripWidthType= DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea.AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
```

However I do not get the right result. Indeed, all my chart area is underlined by the strip line..

Here is a plot to illustrate what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Plz everyone, 9 times viewed and no answer :S

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I completed the post with a picture to illustrate my purpose.

Comment: Not exactly, I want to fill all the chart area between both points, not just under the line. I always thought to use a spline area and to set as Y values the max value of the plot between both points and the min when the line is outside of the period. But I would prefer a solution with striplines due to their low consumption.

Comment: Furthermore, I always use a spline area as you can see on the picture. If you prefer I want to fill my specific period by using a vertical stripline which has a stripwitdh equals to the period between both points.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit obscure: your code is striplining the area vertically from 8:50 to 9:10 A.M.

Do you want to create Stripline every (x):50 to (x+1):10 ?

```
for(int i=0;i<24;i++)
{
    var stripLine = new StripLine();
    stripLine.BackColor = Color.White;
    stripLine.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
    stripLine.BackImageTransparentColor = Color.White;
    stripLine.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Transparent;
    stripLine.Interval = (double)i;
    stripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
    stripLine.IntervalOffset = 50;
    stripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
    stripLine.StripWidth = 20;
    stripLine.StripWidthType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
}
```

Should work.

Do you want to show the StripLine exactly at the points you showed?

```
var stripLine = new StripLine();
stripLine.BackColor = Color.White;
stripLine.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
stripLine.BackImageTransparentColor = Color.White;
stripLine.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Transparent;
stripLine.Interval = 9;
stripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
stripLine.IntervalOffset = 28;
stripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
stripLine.StripWidth = 8;
stripLine.StripWidthType= DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
chartArea.AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
```

Is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

A `StripLine` is a **line** and it will only allow you the add colored **rectangles**.

To create an area that follows your spline **curve** you need to either

- draw it in the `PostPaint` event
- or use an extra `Series` of type `SplineArea`

Here is the 2nd way:

[image]

```
..
Series s3 = chart.Series.Add("S3 ");
s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
s3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.SplineArea;

s2.Color = Color.Red;
s3.Color = Color.FromArgb(55, Color.RosyBrown);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    s1.Points.AddXY(i,20 - rnd.Next(10) );
    s2.Points.AddXY(i,17);
    if (i > 10 && i < 20) s3.Points.AddXY(i, s1.Points[i].YValues[0]);
}
```